How does spring pitch affect stiffness in compression spring design equations?
I'm designing a compression spring and I'm confused about the relationship between spring pitch and stiffness. The spring constant equation I'm using is $k = (Gd^4) / (8D^3N)$, where $G$ is the shear modulus, $d$ is the wire diameter, $D$ is the mean coil diameter, and $N$ is the number of active coils. I notice that neither pitch nor wire length appears in this equation. Does this mean that as long as I have the same number of coils, it doesn't matter how tall those coils are or how much space they occupy? In other words, if I keep $N$, $d$, and $D$ constant, but change the spacing between coils (pitch), will the spring stiffness remain the same? I'm trying to understand how pitch relates to stiffness in spring design, particularly for a spring I plan to 3D print in PLA.

https://pages.hmc.edu/dym/16-JMD2009SpringRates.pdf has the length as $$L = \frac{ N \pi D }{\cos \alpha}$$ where $\alpha$ is the helix angle (related to the pitch). So in the stiffness formula replace one $N D$ with $ \frac{L \cos \alpha}{\pi}$

Section 3.2 of the paper linked above talks about the pitch angle effects.
